# Haskell Trace Function

Tags: haskell, recursion, trace

I am on a mac and I am running Haskell through the command line. This is my code I am recursively reversing a list.

```
import Debug.Trace
reverse1 :: (Show a) => [a] -> [a]  
reverse1 [] = []  
reverse1 (x:xs) = trace(“input xs: “ ++ show xs) $ reverse1 xs ++ [x]
```

The assignment is to do it recursively and also show the trace. It does the reverse if I remove the trace information once I add it, it breaks. This is the error I receive.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( reverse.hs, interpreted )

reverse.hs:4:24: lexical error at character '\8220'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Because you use Unicode Double Quotation Marks instead of ordinary `"` - which is precisely what the error message points at.

Comment: Doesn't `-XUnicodeSyntax` help with... Oh, OK, apparently it doesn't. Maybe somebody should request it...

Answer (score 8):

You have a copy and paste problem: your code snippet uses fancy quotes (`“`) instead of normal ones (`"`) and Haskell doesn't know how to parse it.

In the error message, "lexical error" means that there is a problem with your syntax; specifically, it doesn't know what to do with the character `'\8220'` which is the ASCII representation of `“`.

Assuming your console properly supports Unicode, you can see what character an escape code like this corresponds to with `putStrLn`:

```
Prelude GHC.Exts> putStrLn "\8220"
“
```

This might help you understand similar error messages in the future.

If you're in Emacs, another option is to use the command `C-x 8 <RET>` which allows you to input a Unicode character by number (`8220` in this case). Unfortunately, Emacs expects a number in hexadecimal and Haskell provides one in base-10, so you have to be explicit about your radix:

```
C-x 8 <RET> #10r8220
“
```

Comment: Okay how do I get normal ones. Whenever I add them it adds them like that automatically how do I change that?

Comment: @ChelseaCarl: That sounds like a problem with your editor or your OS setup. I can't necessarily help you with that, so I suggest you ask another question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) about how to type a normal quote, including your editor, OS and keyboard layout in the question details.